# Change product page to show Upsells on right side

Tags: product

I'm busy with a webshop for selling flowers and my customer want's to have the product page layout like the example below.

[image: Example from www.topbloemen.nl]

I need some ideas on how to change the layout but not sure where to start.

Any ideas on how to get the layout to show 2 or more upsells like the example?

Answer (score 1):

In `catalog.xml`,

```
<catalog_product_view...>
....
        <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
             <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
             <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
        </block>
```

Then in your template, you can just call:

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento is defaultly included upsell section on product page.Generally it is calling  in it content area.

using be code:

```
 <catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
............
    <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
        <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>6</columns></action>
        <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>6</limit></action>
    </block>
    ...
```

and on view.phtml that upsell is called by `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products');?>`

If you need customization according to your Layout.Just if you call `2-col-right layout` then you need remove this code from  `<reference name="content">`

and put it reference  right content area

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
<reference name="right">
<block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
    <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>6</columns></action>
    <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>6</limit></action>
</block>
</reference>
<catalog_product_view>
```

Another thing it note that you cannot cart directly .

I suggest use [Custom option](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/create-custom-variants-and-options-of-a-product)  for your  [case](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/difference-between-custom-variants-options-and-configurable-product-type).